# How I do check_game_state method in tictactoe game?

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I want to understand whether the game is finished or drawn or still playable. But I want to do it with dynamic code.

For example I do it static for 3*3 tictactoe game like this :

```
private static boolean check_game_state(char[] board)
{
    if (    (board[0]==cSymbol && board[1]==cSymbol && board[2]==cSymbol) 
         || (board[3]==cSymbol && board[4]==cSymbol && board[5]==cSymbol) 
         || (board[6]==cSymbol && board[7]==cSymbol && board[8]==cSymbol)
         || (board[0]==cSymbol && board[3]==cSymbol && board[6]==(cSymbol))
         || (board[1]==(cSymbol) && board[4]==(cSymbol) && board[7]==(cSymbol))
         || (board[2]==(cSymbol) && board[5]==(cSymbol) && board[8]==(cSymbol))
         || (board[0]==(cSymbol) && board[4]==(cSymbol) && board[8]==(cSymbol))
         || (board[2]==(cSymbol) && board[4]==(cSymbol) && board[6]==(cSymbol)))
    {
        if (cSymbol == 'X')
        {
            state = 5;  //player 1 win
        }
        else if (cSymbol == 'O')
        {
            state = 4; player 2 win
        } 
    }
}
```

I want to it dynamically for a 4*4 or 5*5 or higher board. But how can I do it? Is it possible?

Comment: a little piece of midterm project in android :) I do it static for 3*3 with minimax alg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding the indices, you need to access the elements in a loop.  E.g. instead of

```
boolean test = (board[0]==cSymbol && board[1]==cSymbol && board[2]==cSymbol);
```

You would do something like

```
boolean test = true;
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
  test = test && board[i] == cSymbol ;
}
```

where `length` is the size of the board (e.g. 5, 6), same as square root of the `board.length`  You need to either calculate this from the array length or pass it to the function along with the array itself

This will set `test` to true only if all elements were equal to `cSymbol`, `false` otherwise.

Update: I give you the calculation for the rows; you will need to adopt this to the *columns* (hint: calculate index `i+j*length`), *main dialonal* (index: `i*length+i`) and *sub-diagonal* (index: `i*length+(length-1-i)`).  The index `i*length + j` translates to the `i`th row, `j`th column:

```
private static boolean check_game_state(char[] board, int length) 
{ 
  bool row = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    bool innerRow = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < length; ++j) { // calculate the ith row
      innerRow = innerRow && board[i*length+j] == cSymbol;
    }
    row = row || innerRow;
  }
  if (row) 
  { 
    // somebody won...
  } 
}
```

Comment: it is work all code ?  I mean I want to same thing in my question but i write it static. I want to dnyamic . edit check_game_state() method so it be dynamic . thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't hard code your check conditions then. You will have to have `3` separate cases:

1. To check for rows
2. To check for columns
3. To check for diagonals

You can use simple loops in all those cases which run from `0` to `N` (size of your game). I would say, keep a track of the current cell which is being filled. Say that is `x,y`. Now use this coordinate and check that particular `row` and `column`. And if `x == y` then its on the forward diagonal so you check for it. Similarly check for the reverse diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hard code it, you should implement some algorithm of searching winning positions etc. Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43622/Solve-Tic-Tac-Toe-with-the-MiniMax-algorithm for instance.

Comment: { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, 
                   { 6, 7, 8 }, { 0, 3, 6 }, 
                   { 1, 4, 7 }, { 2, 5, 8 }, 
                   { 0, 4, 8 }, { 2, 4, 6 }  it is static too
                   };

Comment: don't understand your down vote. There is a difference between static data and static logic. One thing is you statically define something - a board for instance. But the other thing is that you hardcode IF statements - this is poor code. But static INITIAL data is OK.